# VIM 8.0 key mapping not working

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I have a VIM 8.0 on my linux machine. I am trying to map `Ctrl + j` and `Ctrl + k` to
`Ctrl + e` and `Ctrl + y` for scrolling.
My `.vimrc` configuration is as follows

```
nmap <C-k> <C-e>
nmap <C-j> <C-y>
```

I don't know if I'm missing something but the mapping seems to be not working.

Comment: Are `<C-e>` or `<C-y>` mapped to anything other than the default?

Comment: No i don't have other mappings related to <C-e> and <C-y>. At least not in my  .vimrc. But i have these mappings for easier window naviagatio nnmap <C-h> <C-w>h
nmap <C-j> <C-w>j
nmap <C-k> <C-w>k
nmap <C-l> <C-w>l

Comment: If you want to exchange the meaning of two keys you should use the :noremap
command.  For example: >
   :noremap k j
   :noremap j k

Comment: Please look what your mappings really are first: `:verbose nmap <C-k>` what is the output of this. Read about `:h recursive_mapping` you nearly always want `nnoremap` instead of `nmap`

Comment: Thanks @DoktorOSwaldo, I was able to figure out the issue using the :verbose command. Eventhough i did't have those key mappings in my vimrc, Turns out that those keys are already mapped  in a vim-plugin which i recently installed. That helped a lot.

Comment: @Eskinder glad to help you wil find a lot of answers here/on vi.stackexchange how to overwrite plugin settings, have a look here https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13537/why-is-set-noexpandtab-in-my-vimrc-ignored-when-i-open-a-file/13538#13538